# For-loop isn't working, only prints the first number in a range

Tags: python

I am trying to print the numbers 20 through to 25 using this code:

```
for index in range(20, 26):
    print(index)
```

This code is in the middle of other code, that doesn't interact with it in any way. However for some reason it is only printing the first number of this range, 20. This might be because the loop ends short because there is code after it, I'm not sure. I hope this is descriptive enough, but all I want is this code to display:

```
20
21
22
23
24
25
```

vertically.

**Edit:**
Here's the code in its entirety:

```
def allow(will_wont):
    print(will_wont + ", ok sure")
    if will_wont == "yes":
        import time
        numbers = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "four", "seventeen"]
        integers = [1, 9, 7, 6, 8, 2, 3, 10, 3, 4, 3, 1, 7]
        loop_number = 8
        numbers.insert(5, "five")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        integers.sort()
        print(numbers.index("one"))
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print(numbers.count("four"))
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print(numbers[3])
        time.sleep(0.5)
        number = input("what number comes next: ")
        if number == "four" or 4:
            print("correct, it was four")
        else:
            print("fail, it was four")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print(numbers[5])
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print(integers[7])
        time.sleep(0.5)

        def num(num1, num2):
            if num1 > num2:
                return num1
            elif num2 > num1:
                return num2

        print(num(7, 5))

        def num(num1, num2):
            if num1 > num2:
                return num1
            elif num2 > num1:
                return num2

        time.sleep(0.5)
        small_number = input("select a number smaller than 8 (in int form pls):")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print("your number was" + small_number)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        if int(small_number) < 8:
            print("8> " + small_number + " thus your choice doesn't matter and 8 will be chosen anyway, take an L")
        else:
            print("you didn't listen to me, so the number will now be ")
            time.sleep(1)
            print("8")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("time for loops")
        while loop_number <= 15:
            loop_number += 1
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print(loop_number)
            time.sleep(0.5)
        print("end of loop")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print(numbers[7])
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print("guess what number comes next (use lowercase text bcos im bad at code) ")
        guess_number = "eighteen"
        guess = ""
        while guess != guess_number:
            guess = input("guess here: ")
            time.sleep(0.5)
        print("nicely done, good job counting! ")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print("this time you only get 3 guesses, try guessing the next number, lowercase text pls")
        guess_number2 = "nighteen"
        guess2 = ""
        guess_count = 0
        guess_limit = 3
        no_more_guesses = False
        finished = False
        while guess2 != guess_number2 and not no_more_guesses and not finished:
            if guess_count < guess_limit:
                guess2 = input("enter guess here: ")
                guess_count += 1

            else:
                no_more_guesses = True
            if no_more_guesses:
                print("fail, the correct guess was nineteen")
            elif guess2 == "nineteen":
                print("correct the number was nineteen")
                finished = True
                time.sleep(0.5)
                print("index time")
                print("for index in range 20-25")
                for index in range(20, 26):
                    print(index)
                    input("damn my index doesn't work properly it only printed the fist number, idk why")

                    outro = input("do you want to hear my outro? yes or no?")
                    if outro == "yes":
```

Comment: The code seems fine, can you provide more context please?

Comment: Whitespace error, most likely (not guaranteed). Because it is running the loop (with nothing in it), then the print statement afterwards. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15230393/python-forloop-only-runs-once-project-euler might help. EDIT: are you defining index as 20 prioir?

Comment: whitespace error would have printed the last index not first

Comment: The print statement under the for loop should be indented by a tab.

Comment: whitespace error would also have resulted in a syntax error, without printing anything

Comment: True I meant if there was at least some kind of assignment in for loop that was omitted print would have printed the last index but never first

Comment: This answer has been edited multiple times changing the code, we should wait for OP to update with the original version.

Comment: The code shown is syntactically incorrect. If the print() invocation is indented then this would work as expected

Comment: Sorry for not providing enough explanation, I edited it adding more of the code, I hope this helps more, also please explain a solution simply since im awful at python, thanks for taking ur time with a nuff nuff like me

Comment: BTW, `if number == "four" or 4:` will always be true.

Comment: Oh, damn, it has more mistakes in it than I realized, thanks for bringing that to my attention.

Comment: Actually your index works fine. The code is waiting for an input. press enter and the code moves to the next line

Comment: So if I press enter when in the run screen it will print the next number out?

Comment: @KhaiTschuemperlin yes, it will, when the code reaches the end of the for loop, it will iterate again. Look at my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# code snippet from the end of the code you provided
for index in range(20, 26):
    print(index)
    input("damn my index doesn't work properly it only printed the fist number, idk why")

    outro = input("do you want to hear my outro? yes or no?")
    if outro == "yes":
        print("Too bad")
```

Output: 
[image]

I assume you wanted to do this:

```
for index in range(20, 26):
    print(index)
    # input("damn my index doesn't work properly it only printed the fist number, idk why")
    print("My index works now")
    time.sleep(0.5)

# Indent the remaining part out of the for loop
outro = input("do you want to hear my outro? yes or no?")
if outro == "yes":
    print("Too bad")
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Omg, thank you so very much, I had no idea it worked like that. How can I get it just to print the numbers and not the text repeatedly?

Comment: @KhaiTschuemperlin Check my edit. I hope that is what you are looking for. Note that when you use `input` the code stops and waits for a user input so I would recommend indicating that an input is required using something like `input("blah blah: ")` or `input("> ")`

Comment: You are a legend, thank you so very much, that solves my problem!